# Django: new project keeps looking for a settings folder

Tags: python, django, wsgi, django-settings

So I started a new django project on a system that has another project. I use subdomains and mod_wsgi to handle the direction to the various projects. The direction seems to be working just fine.

For some reason, though, this second project is insist my urls.py and settings.py files should be located at settings/urls.py and settings/settings.py. Any ideas? It completely ignores the perfectly valid urls.py file that's sitting there (with a couple of filters as test urls). It also ignores any urls.py files I actually put at settings/urls.py (as a test). I made `ROOT_URLCONF='urls'` as opposed to `ROOT_URLCONF='projectname.urls'` as django never seems to like the former.

Anyway, I'm completely stumped, and after a couple of hours searching through everything, I can't for the life of me figure out where I should even look. Any ideas?

Comment: are these 2 seperate projects? or did you combine two projects into one?  What does your .wsgi file look like? I think you can specify exactly where your settings module is in it.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think your problem might actually be that you have `ROOT_URLCONF` set to `urls` instead of `<proj_name>.urls` so it is searching for `settings.urls.py` because your ROOT_URLCONF tells it to go to urls.py which would be settings.urls.py while in the `settings` module.

Second, in your wsgi file, do you have the following line:

```
s.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'
```